# Extra characters are being displayed after closing <html> tag

Tags: html, xhtml, dreamweaver

I'm working on a website and since time ago I've been realized that some extra characters are being displayed at the end of the pages. To be more specific, it's the "greater than" character ( > ) is put automatically during get a page through FTP. See the end code:

```
<div class="telefones_contato">
                      <p class="titulo_tc">Se  preferir fale conosco <br />
                       através dos telefones:</p>
                      <p class="telefone_tc"> 11 0000 0000<br />
                          11 0000 0000</p>

                          <div class="curriculo">
                            <p class="cv_texto">
                            Quer fazer parte da nossa equipe?<br />
                            Mande seu curriculo para:<br />
                            test@email.com<br />
                            </p>
                          </div>

                </div>
    </div>
</div>


</div>



</body>

</html>>>>>>>
```

See that, after closing html tag, Dreamweaver puts ">>>>>>>" after.

I have no idea why those characteres are being "generated" on the page.

Can someone help?? Have you ever seen this issue before?

Comment: Please post the code in your question.

Comment: I tried to paste the code but the syntax gets broken.

Answer (score 1):

I've seem this a lot with Dreamweaver. If you're using WYSIWYG in Dreamweaver is notorious for adding extra code. Open up the raw document with a text editor or Notepad++ or something and see if the >>>> show up in the raw file. If so, delete the extra characters, save, open and refresh using CTRL+F5 for PC and see if it's still present in the new edited document outside of Dreamweaver. CTRL+F5 deletes the cached page and reloads from scratch. Often times if you don't use this method of refreshing it will show the cached page and will not show your recent edits you just saved out.